# React Getting State Provider method

Tags: reactjs, redux

If I understand correctly, the provider component/method gives access to store in redux, without importing it directly within each component. Assuming my understanding is correct, then I was wondering why I am unable to get store.getState() in App.js. It says the store is undefined....

Index.js

```
const store = createStore(allReducers,{})

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.Js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(store.getState())
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="individual"> 
            <House/>
          <NameTag/>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **should not** normally try to access the store that way.

While you *can* manually write the code to subscribe to the Redux store in your React components, **there's absolutely no reason to write that code yourself**.  The wrapper components generated by React-Redux's `connect` function already have that store subscription logic taken care of for you.  Those wrapper components also use the `mapStateToProps` functions you give them to extract the data each component needs from the Redux state.  So, you *won't* be calling `store.getState()` in your components themselves.

Also, `connect` does a *lot* of work to ensure that your actual components only re-render when they actually need to.  That includes lots of memoization work, and comparisons against the props from the parent component and the values returned by your `mapStateToProps` function for that component.  By not using `connect`, you're giving up all those performance improvements, and your components will be unnecessarily re-rendering all the time.

Third, if you manually reference the store in your components (either via direct import or via context), you're directly coupling them together, thus making it harder to test the components.  I personally try to keep my components "unaware" of Redux.  They never reference `props.dispatch`, but rather call pre-bound action creators like `this.props.someFunction()`.  The component doesn't "know" that it's a Redux action creator - that function could be a callback from a parent component, a bound-up Redux action creator, or a mock function in a test, thus making the component more reusable and testable.

For more info, see:

- The [Redux FAQ section on performance](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html)
- The [Redux FAQ entry on connecting multiple components](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-multiple-components)
- The [Redux FAQ entry on components re-rendering too often](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-rendering-too-often)
- The [Redux FAQ entry on importing the store directly](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/StoreSetup.html#store-setup-multiple-stores)
- The [Redux Performance](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-performance.md#redux-performance) section of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links)
- And finally, my blog post [Practical Redux, Part 6: Connected Lists, Forms, and Performance](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-6-connected-lists-forms-and-performance/).

Source: I'm a Redux maintainer, and author of the Redux FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

store is handled in Provider class with the help of React Context api.

If you want to access store in a React Component, you will have to define contextTypes in class like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object,
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.context)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="individual">
          <House/>
          <NameTag/>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to go on details, you can study here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Comment: However, note that you **should not** normally access the store directly this way.  Use the React-Redux `connect()` function to create wrapper components that will manage the store subscription for you instead.

Comment: @markerikson I agree. If we have to access some values from the store, then we should use connect() function to create a wrapper. But I have come across a situation in which I need to handle two Provider Component in a single application sharing the same store. In that situation, I have used context types to get the store.

Comment: Uh... that doesn't make sense. Are you saying _two_ Redux Providers wrapped around each other?  Or a Redux Provider and a component related to some other library?

Comment: No..they aren't wrapped around each other. They are siblings in the DOM.

Comment: Then you use `connect`, and render `<Provider store={store}><ConnectedComp1 /></Provider>` and `<Provider store={store}><ConnectedComp2 /></Provider>` in separate places.  Pass the same store object to both Providers.  But, the point of `connect()` is that it handles accessing the store out of React's context - you shouldn't have to do so in your own code.  In fact, you can render the same connected component class in both component trees, and it will work right.

Comment: @markerikson By using connect, How can I access the store? Even connect do not pass store as a prop to the container component.

Comment: `connect` accesses the store using React's `context` mechanism, which makes variables available to any descendant component .  So, any connected component inside a `<Provider>` can access the store. But, the point is that `connect` abstracts that process, so that you don't have to write the code yourself. Also, the context API will change in some future version of React. At that time, we will update `connect` to use the new API, and your own code won't have to change at all.

Answer (score 0):

Although [Redux's docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) say

> The option we recommend is to use a special React Redux component called `<Provider>` to [**magically**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) make the store available to all container components in the application without passing it explicitly.

They link the word [**magically**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) to react's **Context** feature.

So `store` is available on the `context` object, which you can access through `this.context` inside your App component, however make sure you know [how to use context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html#how-to-use-context) first